# How to write multi column header in xlsxwriter using python code?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am working on a problem of table extraction from image and reconstruction table in excel format. By applying some DL techniques and some python code, I am getting list of rows and columns of table. I am using xlsxwriter to create excel file in python. sometime In my table I have a cells which is header for multiple column.[image: you can see the image, let I have table like this where "a" is header for column 1 and 2, and "b" is header for column 3 and column 4]

I have written below python code to structure this table in excel, you can see how I am getting lists rows and cols.

```
import xlsxwriter
rows=[["a","b"],['1','2','3','4']]
cols=[['a','1'],['a','2'],['b','3'],['b','4']]
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('table.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for i,row in enumerate(rows):
    for j,col in enumerate(cols):
        for el in row:
            if el in col:
                worksheet.write(i, j, el)
workbook.close()
```

After running this code I am getting table like this,
[image: "a" is header for column 1 and 2 so instead of merging, it is showing in both column 1 and 2, same for header "b"]

[image: this is my expected result]

How can I get such a result in python using xlsxwriter or any other method?

Answer (score 0):

This will give the desired result but probably isn't an ideal solution because the ranges for the merged headers are hard-coded.

Splitting the header row from the data might help in  avoiding that.

```py
import xlsxwriter
rows=[["a","b"],['1','2','3','4']]
cols=[['a','1'],['a','2'],['b','3'],['b','4']]
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('table.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for i,row in enumerate(rows):
    for j,col in enumerate(cols):
        for el in row:
            if el in col:
                worksheet.write(i, j, el)
                
center_format = workbook.add_format({
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter'})                
worksheet.merge_range("A1:B1", "a", center_format)
worksheet.merge_range("C1:D1" ,"b", center_format)
workbook.close()
```